# Upload files on remote server through html & javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I am trying to upload files through html page in our unix based server but I don't know how to take the files on remote server & save files there.

I write the following code please help me to connect it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Upload()
{

var filename = document.getElementById("filename").value;

var storepath = "HOSTURL/Foldername";

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="filename" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="Upload" />
</form
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that you haven't set the `action` on your form, what you've got should allow you to upload a file to your server (the javascript you have is completely unnecessary). At that point it's all server-side processing. What are you using on your server?

Comment: If you really do need to use Javascript (feedback when uploading etc) then dont reinvent the wheel - use one of the many javascript file uploaders like [this](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) one.  But still easier to just post the file to a server using traditional methods.

Comment: I am not able to save file on the specified location. Please let me know how can i do that.

Answer (score 2):

Why using JavaScript? You can simple use the html form to post your file to the server:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/foo/bar.ext" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="filename" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Change the form `action` to the location you want to post the file to.

Comment: I am using this & when I test on my local machine it only take me on the action URL & not upload any file there.

Comment: I am not able to save file on the specified location. Please let me know how can i do that.

Comment: What language do you use php, asp.net etc.? And maybe it's better to create a new question.

Comment: I need to work through HTMl & javascript. You can use Jsp file also.

Comment: I need to save my file through HTML script on a particular location. Please let me know how can i save my file on my remote location.

Comment: You need to have server-side code to save your file, I don't have JSP knowledge so it's better to create a new question.

Comment: Let me know here we can call here anything through their refrence like HTML. is there any function available in HTML or javascript to working with files & transfer it to local system to another location.

Answer (score 2):

PHP would be a better choice for this.

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST["Upload"] ) )
{
    $target_path = "uploads/";

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    <input type="file" name="filename" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: I only need too do that with HTML & javascript... thanks but no need of PHP code. It's goog if You can help me through HTML & javascript.